# Changing the CameraPreview Aspect Ratio (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app where I have a `Scaffold` with an `AppBar` and a bottom Ads Banner.

In between, there is the `CameraPreview` from the camera plugin in Flutter.

As the `CameraPreview` is made to take the aspect ratio of the device/camera, the `CameraPreview` doesn't take the entire available space, leaving extra space on most devices.

I tried to crop the `CameraPreview` to show only whatever fits in the available space. It worked, but now the preview is stretched out

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
        final cameraController = controller.cameraController!;
        if(cameraController.value.previewSize != null) {
            return ClipRect(
                child: OverflowBox(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                        height: constraints.maxWidth,
                        child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                            child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
                            ),
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
            );
        } else {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
        }
    },
)
```

I tried other solutions like `Transform.scale`, but that only zooms into the preview, it doesn't change the ratio or the stretching.

Looking solutions in the package itself doesn't help either, most similar issues are stalling or already closed for stalling.

What am I supposed to do here? Am I supposed to manually clip the preview's value?

Answer (score 1):

check this below code,

Use get screen size by MediaQuery & calculate scale for aspect ratio widget and add CameraPreview() to it like below

```
    // get screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    // calculate scale for aspect ratio widget
    var scale = cameraController.value.aspectRatio / size.aspectRatio;

    // check if adjustments are needed...
    if (cameraController.value.aspectRatio < size.aspectRatio) {
      scale = 1 / scale;
    }

return Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      child: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Complete code**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        if (controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
          //stop video
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: cameraScreen(),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .1,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        //can add Controls
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cameraScreen() {
    final CameraController cameraController = controller;
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Loading Camera...",
            style: CameraTextStyle.cameraUtilLoadingStyle(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return cameraWidget(context, cameraController);
    }
  }

  Widget cameraWidget(context, cameraController) {
    // get screen size
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    // calculate scale for aspect ratio widget
    var scale = cameraController.value.aspectRatio / size.aspectRatio;

    // check if adjustments are needed...
    if (cameraController.value.aspectRatio < size.aspectRatio) {
      scale = 1 / scale;
    }

    return Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      child: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget cameraSwitch() {
    final CameraController cameraController = controller;
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          if (cameraController != null &&
              cameraController.value.isInitialized &&
              !cameraController.value.isRecordingVideo) {
            if (cameras.isNotEmpty) {
              if (selectedCamera == cameras[0]) {
                selectedCamera = cameras[1];
                onNewCameraSelected(selectedCamera);
              } else {
                selectedCamera = cameras[0];
                onNewCameraSelected(selectedCamera);
              }
            }
          }
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.switch_camera,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't change the aspect ratio of the camera, it just zooms in. Plus, the `AspectRatio` widget will just make the camera preview stretched out